# regex matching for string with character limit, specific start characters, and termination

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to extract specific portions of a url string. A simplified example is looking for any string in a url that starts with "who" or "what", has a total length of either 5 or 10 characters and stops matching on any non-alpha numeric string

for example:

`http://www.test.com/who12/foo` -> `who12` //5 char match starting with who and ending at the `/`

`http://www.test.com/who1234567/foo` -> `who1234567` //10 char match starting with who and ending at the `/`

`http://www.test.com/what1` -> `what1` //5 char match at the end of the string

`http://www.test.com/what1?param=true` -> `what1` //5 char match breaking on the `?`

I've tried setting something up 
[here](https://regex101.com/r/ZcMbwi/1)

It breaks on the / in the 5 and 10 char scenarios but fails on the `?` case and the case where the match is at the end of the string.

Is there a simpler approach to accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```
\.com\/\K(?:who[^\/?\s]{2}|what[^\/?\s])(?:[^\/?\s]{5})?
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NQeCmo/6).

Use a capturing approach if PCRE `\K` match reset operator is not supported:

```
\.com\/((?:who[^\/?\s]{2}|what[^\/?\s])(?:[^\/?\s]{5})?)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NQeCmo/5)

**Details**:

- `\.com\/` - match `.com/` so as to find the necessary left hand side context for the text you need
- `(?:who[^\/?\s]{2}|what[^\/?\s])(?:[^\/?\s]{5})?` - two alternatives and optional 5 chars after either of them:

  - `who[^\/?\s]{2}` - `who` followed with 2 chars other than `/`, `?` and whitespace
  - `|` -  or
  - `what[^\/?\s]` - `what` followed with 1 char other than `/`, `?` and whitespace, and then...
- `(?:[^\/?\s]{5})?` - *optional* 5 chars other than `/`, `?` and whitespace.

Comment: this can also be simplified a bit for prefixes with the same length: https://regex101.com/r/9N5a55/1

Comment: @john_ryan: You must have meant *for suffixes* (what comes to the right of the alternation). Still, the approach is the same.

Comment: i don't think so i meant that if the prefixes are the same length (in the case i posted who and why are both 3) you don't need to add the `[^\/?\s]{2}` (or some variation) to each prefix to satisfy the minimum length, they can just be or'd together directly. In any case I think your answer is more useful for different prefix lengths (i.e. who and what)

Comment: Well, that is why it looks so cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following regex.

**Regex:** `(?=.{5,10})(?:who|what)(?:[^\/?\s]*)`

**Explanation:**

- `(?=.{5,10})` lookahead checks for length of string to be 5 to 10 characters.
- `(?:who|what)` matches literals `who` or `what`.
- `[^\/?\s]*` is negated-character class for `/`,`?`,`\s (whitespace)`. Hence other character than these will be matched.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pn1LAj/2/)**

Comment: thanks that is awesome, any suggestions for exactly 5 or 10 digit match? i tried swapping the first segment with `(?=(?:.{5}|.{10})$)` (from another SO question, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: also this doesn't handle a few important cases, see: https://regex101.com/r/5yZBNa/1

Comment: @john_ryan: Okay so you want **exactly**  5 or 10 digits ?

Comment: Ideally yes, I just did the range because I was having issues with or-ing the length

Comment: [Check this out](https://regex101.com/r/pn1LAj/3/). If this works for you I will add it in solution.

Comment: i updated it https://regex101.com/r/pn1LAj/4, it doesn't seem to filter on the length